# Testing Dropwizard Resources gives NPE

Tags: junit, jersey, dropwizard

I am trying to unit test a resource by creating a ResourceTestRule as follows

```
 @ClassRule
  public static final ResourceTestRule RESOURCES =
      ResourceTestRule.builder().addResource(new UserRequestsResource(edao, udao)).build();


@Test
  public void invalidEnvironment_NameWithUnderscore_Returns400() throws Exception {
    Entity<?> entity = Entity.entity(userRequest, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE);
    Response response = RESOURCES.client().target(getDeploysPath()).request().post(entity);
    assertEquals(response.getStatus(), 400);
    assertEquals(response.getStatusInfo(), Status.BAD_REQUEST);
    assertThat(response.readEntity(String.class), containsString(
        "{\"Status\":\"'Invalid_Env' contains an underscore; 'Invalid_Env' contains an upper-case letter\"}"));
  }
```

This gives an NPPE at Resource.client()
Following is the stack trace

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.util.Objects.requireNonNull(Objects.java:203)
    at io.dropwizard.testing.common.Resource.getJerseyTest(Resource.java:174)
    at io.dropwizard.testing.common.Resource.client(Resource.java:164)
    at io.dropwizard.testing.junit.ResourceTestRule.client(ResourceTestRule.java:80)
    at com.mathworks.batup.deployer.resources.TestBadEnvironmentName.setup(TestBadEnvironmentName.java:43)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:41)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:27)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runNotIgnored(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:79)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:49)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:193)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:52)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:191)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:42)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:184)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
```

What am I missing?

Comment: I have seen this issue before. What is the version of dropwizard and dropwizard-testing you are using?

Comment: I get this with PowerMockRunner. (dw 1.3.12, mockito 2.28.2, powermock 2.0.2).